# Loading database driver .jar in django-jython project

Tags: java, django, classpath, jython

I have attempted to follow the instructions found on http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonDjango.html#starting-a-project-and-an-pp to no avail.  When I try this I get a ClassNotFound error.  So I've done some searching and I've found this page http://jythonpodcast.hostjava.net/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixB.html#working-with-classpath but I'm not sure how to make this work with a django project.

I am going to deploy this webapp in a war file on an apache tomcat server.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using?  You should try the following at the command line in Windows:

set CLASSPATH= path to jar

on macosx

export CLASSPATH= path to jar